# Raise an exception on another thread in iOS/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, exception

Is there a way to raise an exception on another thread in iOS/Objective-C?

What I am trying to do is create something like Java's Thread.interrupt() and InterruptedException do (see [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)) ? This exception is raised on a thread when someone calls the thread's interrupt method, thus allowing another thread to signal a proposed termination.

Comment: I'm not much of an Objective-C dev but it sounds to me like you need to shift your thinking from Java patterns (like exceptions) to the appropriate patterns/constructs in Objective-C. Perhaps message passing?

Comment: +1 Matt, exceptions are _exceptional_ in Objective-C and are only ever used by Apple's own frameworks to indicate programmer error, not for regular program flow.

Comment: There's a use case in there. The reference to Java was only for easy explanation. Please bear with me for the moment :-)

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Exceptions are appropriate constructs in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Is [`-[NSThread cancel]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/cancel) what you're looking for? It doesn't raise an exception, but it allows another thread to signal a proposed termination.

Comment: It's not the full solution. The goal is to raise an exception on the "interrupted" thread, without the interrupted thread having to cooperate.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, exceptions can only be raised in the current thread in Objective-C. You can try kill a thread immediately with `pthread` functions, but that might not be what you're after either.

Comment: @TomDalling Exceptions can be raised in any thread in Objective-c.

Comment: @Raffi Yes, obviously, but that is not what the question is asking for. Please read more carefully.

Comment: @TomDalling "As far as I'm aware, exceptions can only be raised in the current thread in Objective-C."

Comment: @Raffi "current" does not imply a single thread. I think you're getting the current thread confused with the main thread.

Comment: @TomDalling Ok, I see what you're saying now, that you can't raise an exception in one thread from a different thread.